# mongodb directory is empty in WSL Ubuntu 20.04 installation of mogodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am able to start mongdb server using the following command:`sudo mongod --dbpath ~/data/db`.
However, with `sudo service mongod start`, the service fails to start.
I tried to check contents and permissions of the various mongo and mongodb directories created, but I find that `ls -l /var/lib/mongodb/` is empty but I am not sure what that means.
What am I missing?

Edit:
I tried the following commands and it worked, which would mean that the dbpath was somehow not associated with the default path which made the `sudo service mongod start` to fail.
But how did the service automatically start when I provided the dbpath with `sudo mongod --dbpath ~/data/db`?

````
sudo mongod --repair --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
sudo mongod --fork --logpath /var/lib/mongodb/mongodb.log --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
sudo service mongod start```
````

Answer (score 0):

`mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb` starts the service and stores data in `/var/lib/mongodb`

`mongod --dbpath ~/data/db` starts the service and stores data in `~/data/db`, where `~` is your home directory.

`sudo mongod --dbpath ~/data/db` starts the service and stores data in `~/data/db`, where `~` is either your personal home directory the home directory of user **root**. Looks like some Linux derivatives preserve `HOME` variable whereas other do not when using `sudo`.

`mongod` starts the service and stores data in `/data/db` (or for Windows: `\data\db` on current drive)

`service mongod start` reads the service files (check with `service mongod status`) and uses the dbPath defined in there. Defaults are these:

| Platform | Package Manager | Default `storage.dbPath` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RHEL / CentOS and Amazon | yum | `/var/lib/mongo` |
| SUSE | zypper | `/var/lib/mongo` |
| Ubuntu and Debian | apt | `/var/lib/mongodb` |
| macOS | brew | `/usr/local/var/mongodb` |
| Windows | MSI | `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\{release}\data\` |

So, it's your choice!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. ```service mongod start``` explanation was helpful.